# Rotating text in postscript

Tags: postscript

I have the following postscript code:

```
/outputtext {
   /data exch def
   /rot exch def
   /xfont exch def
   /Times-Roman findfont
   xfont scalefont
   setfont
   /y1 exch def
   /x1 exch def
   x1 y1 moveto
   rot rotate
   data show
} def


% x y fontsize rotation (text) outputtext
20 300 12 0 (text1) outputtext
20 400 12 90 (text2) outputtext
20 500 12 90 (text3) outputtext
20 600 12 0 (text4) outputtext
showpage
```

The function simply outputs text based on a x, y co-ords and the text to display, there is also a variable for rotation.
For some reason when I output text with a rotation of >0 degrees, all other text that comes after that will not work, I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.
In the example above, 'text1' and 'text2' will display, but not 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, needed to do a negative of the rotation (so if it was rotation 90 degrees, it then needs to be rotated -90 degrees)

Needed the following:

```
 rot neg rotate
```

So the function becomes:

```
/outputtext {
   /data exch def
   /rot exch def
   /xfont exch def
   /y1 exch def
   /x1 exch def
   /Times-Roman findfont
   xfont scalefont
   setfont
   x1 y1 moveto
   rot rotate
   data show

   rot neg rotate
} def
```

Answer (score 3):

The `rotate` command in Postscript rotates the entire coordinate space, not an individual drawing operation. `90 rotate` puts all further operations off the top of the sheet.

Comment: If you want to rotate only some text but not the rest on the page, call gsave before rotating and grestore after outputting the text.

Answer (score 2):

As user @pi3 says in a comment:

> If you want to rotate only some text but not the rest on the page, call gsave before rotating and grestore after outputting the text

I believe the answer by @pi3 deserves to be more then just a comment, so let me paste some example code:

```
newpath
200 100 moveto
gsave
90 rotate
(Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet) show
grestore
```

Answer (score 0):

The "rotate" command and Current Transformation Matrix (CTM) is used to rotate the displaying text in Postscript

**rotate**:
45 rotate
10 10 moveto
(Postscript) show

**CTM Matrix**:
[0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0 0 ] concat
10 10 moveto
(Postscript) show